# What is (problem-design) tag for? Is it needed?

Tags: discussion, tagging

I have noticed that there exists [problem-design](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/problem-design) tag, which has at the moment empty [tag-wiki](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/problem-design/info) and contains two questions:

- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/658626/guard-scheduling-problem-simple-greedy-algorithms
- [Designing a probability question with two unknowns but a unique solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/655950/designing-a-probability-question-with-two-unknowns-but-a-unique-solution)

Is this tag really needed? What was the intended usage of this tag?

---

I can imagine the phrase *problem design* in the context of teaching, creating exercises or contest problems. Indeed, when searching [on internet](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22problem+design%22+mathematics) and in [Google Books](http://books.google.com/books?q="problem+design"+mathematics), it seems that some of the hits are in the context of teaching mathematics. One of the questions that currently have this tag is about creating a mathematical problem.